# How to create an Active Objects pattern TypedActor in C#

Tags: c#, akka.net, typedactor

I am new to `Akka.net` and I want to create an `Active Objects` pattern `TypedActor` to bridge between my `actor` code and `non-actor` code.

I read the document for Java at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/typed-actors.html

In the example above a `TypedActor` is created as follows:

```
Squarer mySquarer =
    TypedActor.get(system).typedActorOf(
        new TypedProps<SquarerImpl>(Squarer.class, SquarerImpl.class));
```

I wonder how to do this in `C#`. I try to find this in `Akka.net` document, but the link for `TypedActor` (http://getakka.net/docs/TypedActor) is not available. And there is no equivalent methods found in `C#`.

Can someone give a hand on this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no implementation of `TypedActor` in Akka.NET that corresponds with what's in Akka at the moment. Our `TypedActor` implementation is deprecated and will be replaced with something else in the future.

For the time being, you can use the `Inbox` class to act as a bridge between your actor and non-actor code. http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/E63D0210.htm

We're working on improving our docs, so sorry for the inconvenience :\

Comment: Is there an example how to work with the inbox class?

Comment: Any changes here? Does TypedActor exist now?